# How can i add a simple gui for batch proccess file in python?

Tags: python

How can I add a simple gui for batch process file in python?

I have some code for process files but it can't select files in path to batch process in folder. I want to select folder have *.mp3.* and a button "repair" and save it to new folder name "ok", mp3 renamed to *.mp3 after click "repair" button, here is my code, I have poblem that the second signature
`ID3_START = b'\x49\x44\x33\x04'` can't add, I need some help:

```py
import io

file_names = ["Amaro porano jaha chay western.mp3 - Copy.nlah"] //*.mp3.* error

ID3_START = b'\x49\x44\x33\x03'
ZEROS = b'\x00' * 12

for fname in file_names:
  with open(fname, 'r+b') as f:
    # Find the ID3 block
    while f.read(4) != ID3_START:
      f.seek(-2, io.SEEK_CUR)
      f.write(ZEROS)

    # Drop the last 334 bytes
    f.seek(-334, io.SEEK_END)
    f.truncate()
    print("Repaired")
```

Comment: I suggest that you go through one or two `tkinter` beginner tutorials. After one or two hours of exposure to the library you should be able to code your gui.

Comment: I second @timgeb. Tkinter is the way to go. It's lightweight, comes with python and is relatively intuitive

Comment: i tried but no success :(